# "File:///" path to "href" download link MVC .NET

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hyperlink, filepath

I have a file located locally: C:\foo\test.txt accessible as String.
My MVC application root is: C:\Projects\Websiteroot

What I need is to generate a link that can download that file

But keep in mind:
I can't add virtual folder in application IIS. Because tomorrow that folder will not exist, and I will have to access that file in other folder like: D:\other\folder\test.txt
Or even here: \sharedResource\whateverfolder\test.txt

So all I have is this string, and I need to turn it into http link, like one here:
download

Much appreciated :)

Comment: You need to post some code for everyone to have a look at otherwise we'll be guessing

Comment: `// returns file location on the server
string filePath = getFilePath("testfile","12-09-2014");

//Returns File:/// path
Uri uri = new System.Uri(filePath);

// link that will be used in a Viewas href for download link - HOW DO I GET IT?
string href = "";`  this is a part of my Controller that is supposed to generate a download link. I pass some parameters to it... the point just is that it generates a filepath to me. One like: C:\folder\file.txt or simmilar